# Cómo puedo cambiar el valor de una variable con un endpoint en javascript

Tags: javascript, endpoint

Tengo que subir un código en javascript como servicio a una infrastructura pero hay un parámetro `param` que necesito cambiar durante algunos minutos algunas veces. En python lo he hecho con `@app.route('/param/<string:param>', methods=['GET'])` y dentro cambiando el valor de una variable global. Pero no se como montarlo en javascript ya que no soy tan experto. Por ahora tengo esto:

```
const param = '':

const expressApp = express().use(bodyParser.json());
expressApp.post('/server', app);

expressApp.listen(5100, ()=> {
  console.log("Servidor listo en puerto " + 5100);
});
```

el valor de `param` se tiene que poder utilizar en varios puntos del resto del código pero puedo tenerlo guardado en otro fichero o lo que sea necesario.
Gracias.

Comment: Ya intentaste usar local storage?

Comment: No tiene que depender del navegador o de la sesión. Es un parámetro que hace que cambie la funcionalidad del servicio en todos los sitios cuando yo, como desarrollador decida que tiene que cambiar

Comment: Creo que podrías ayudarte te firebase

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que utilizar un código así:

```
let param = "";

expressApp.get('/param/:param', (req, res, next) => {
  param = req.params['param'];

  // Manejar otras operaciones correspondientes a esta ruta

  // Como estás utilizando GET, supongo que vas a enviar algún dato al cliente
  res.send(data);
})
```

Las variables que se especifican en el `URL` se pueden acceder desde `req.params`, y se especifican como variables colocando `:` en la ruta, seguido del nombre de la variable.

Si solamente quieres cambiar el valor de la variable con la ruta, te recomiendo utilizar `PUT` y retornar simplemente un mensaje `res.send({ message: "Todo salió bien" })`